# Laravel Distinct query is not working in my project

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, am joining more than 2 tables, but the problem is that in the table `location_services`,There is multiple entries with same location_id and services_id. I want to take only one row in such cases.Following is my Query.
What is the problem here.Kindly help me to resolve it

```
   $loc_services = Clinic::select('*')
                        ->join('locations', 'locations.clinicID', '=', 'clinics.clinicID')
                        ->join('location_services', 'location_services.locationID', '=', 'locations.locationID')
                        ->join('services', 'services.serviceID', '=', 'location_services.serviceID')
                        ->whereIn('services.serviceID',$services_id)
                        ->where('clinics.api_key','=',$apiKey) 
                        ->get();
```

Please help.

I want to retrive all data from clinics table which have various services in various locations. Eaach location may or may not have more than one services

Comment: what exactly you want to select? all columns? all columns from clinics table?

Comment: I want all coloumns from clinics table, I have updated details in quetion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `groupBy()` method to achieve the goal. Just add this method before the `get()` method's call.

```
groupBy('location_services.locationID', 'location_services.serviceID')
```

Comment: Where should i add groupBy() clause in query,before get().Can u please write complete query for me

Comment: Yes I meant that. Check out here - https://pastebin.com/9wVRKvbx

Comment: message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'directory.clinics.clinicID' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `clinics` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`clinicID` = `

Comment: Thnaks, i got it working i have changed  'strict' => false to config/database.php